# Learning when was the last time a file is accessed

Tags: operating-system, filesystems, kernel

I was wondering if learning when was the last time a file is accessed is possible. I mean like when a .dll file in windows is used by any other program. I wonder if are there any features in any operating system that keeps a file's last access date, or extensions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unix provides the stat command or the fstat() function to fetch the last access time of a file.

```
eos$ stat file
File: `file'
Size: 280486          Blocks: 548        IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 12h/18d Inode: 1963857568  Links: 1
Access: (0600/-rw-------)  Uid: (83991/ vshesha)   Gid: (  108/    abcd)
Access: 2014-09-16 15:39:09.000000000 -0400
Modify: 2014-09-16 15:39:09.000000002 -0400
Change: 2014-09-16 15:39:09.000000000 -0400
```

For Windows see this [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/351777/how-can-i-know-when-a-file-was-last-read-or-accessed-on-windows)

Answer (score 1):

This is a feature of a filesystem/OS. In case of Windows and it's default file system NTFS, you need to enable the feature first: http://www.groovypost.com/howto/microsoft/enable-last-access-time-stamp-to-files-folder-windows-7/

```
In the cmd prompt, Type in "fsutil behavior set disablelastaccess 0" and press enter.
Restart your PC for changes to take affect
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually all file systems save the file access time.

For example, take a look at [NTFS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724290%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for Windows. Or [ext2](http://www.nongnu.org/ext2-doc/ext2.html#I-ATIME), and older version of the file system commonly used in linux.